# How to convert from name type to account_name type in contract?

Tags: smart-contract

I know how to do the other way round but don't know how to convert from name to account_name unless I convert it to string first. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name structure contains "account_name value" attribute. Look at "eosiolib\types.hpp"

account_name is just uint64_t; (eosiolib\types.h)

So you can:

```
account_name a = N("accname"); //eq of string_to_name(..)
name n = name {a};
a = n;
string accname = n.to_string();
```

Look at hello\hello.cpp for example.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this code can be useful:

```
account_name eosio_name = eosio::string_to_name(user); // convert to EOSIO name from variable
```

Where `user` is: `std::string user`.

This is basically a method to convert an `std::string` to `uint64_t`.